# Creating a new network namespace on Linux

Tags: linux, networking

I'd like to create a new network namespace on Linux.

http://www.spinics.net/lists/linux-containers/msg10895.html tells me that I can attach a shell to an existing namespace with ID X by running:

```
$ chnetns X /bin/sh
```

This works fine if the namespace already exists, but if I try with a non-existent namespace, I get the following:

```
$ chnetns 100 /bin/sh
setsocketopt: Invalid argument
```

How can I create the namespace? I'm on Red Hat Linux, V6.1.

Comment: Quite an old question but I had need of an introduction to linux network namespaces / virtual networking myself.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is 'ip netns add vnet1'.

```
ip netns list
ip netns add vnet1
```

See also **introduction to linux virtual networking**: [blog.scottlowe.org: Linux networking namespaces intro](http://blog.scottlowe.org/2013/09/04/introducing-linux-network-namespaces/), [opencloudblog.com: Linux networking namespaces shiny and more beautiful](http://www.opencloudblog.com/?p=42) and [opencloudblog.com: Linux networking namespaces shiny and even more detailed with beautiful diagrams](http://www.opencloudblog.com/?p=66)

Links to other references to help others get started with virtual networking namespaces. See also also [LWN article on network namespaces](http://lwn.net/Articles/580893/), [Open Stack Networking example](https://openstack.redhat.com/Networking_in_too_much_detail), [iproute2](http://www.linuxfoundation.org/collaborate/workgroups/networking/iproute2), [linux vrf patchset](http://linux-vrf.sourceforge.net/) Virtual Routing and Forwarding for Linux, and [OpenStack networking concepts](http://docs.openstack.org/training-guides/content/module002-ch002-openstack-networking-concepts.html).

[man ip netns](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ip-netns.8.html)

```
NAME
   ip-netns - process network namespace management

SYNOPSIS
   ip [ OPTIONS ] netns  { COMMAND | help }

   ip netns { list }

   ip netns { add | delete } NETNSNAME

   ip netns identify PID

   ip netns pids NETNSNAME

   ip netns exec NETNSNAME command ...

   ip netns monitor
```